# Client/Server communication - Guess my animal game

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to make a simple text based game using multi threading. I have chosen to do a guess my animal game. A server will pick a random animal and give out clues and the client has to guess what the animal is within three clues.

However, if the animal is guessed correct, the program just goes to the next clue. I dont understand where i have gone wrong?

The other problem is when the client says *y* to a new game, it just repeats the same animal. It won't change.

I know it is just the protocol class i need to fix. Please help! I have cried with frustration over this program.

Here is a copy of my protocol class:

```
public class KKProtocol {

    private static final int WAITING = 0;
    private static final int ASKNAME = 1;
    private static final int SENTCLUE = 2;
    private static final int SENTCLUE2 = 3;
    private static final int SENTCLUE3 = 4;
    private static final int ANOTHER = 5;
    private static final int NUMANIMALS = 4;
    private int state = WAITING;
    private int currentAnimal = (int) (Math.random() * 6);  // number of first joke
    private String[] clues = {"I like to play", "I like to scratch", "I eat salad", "I annoy you in the morning"};
    private String[] clues2 = {"Love walks", "House pet", "garden pet", "I fly everywhere"};
    private String[] clues3 = {"Woof", "Meow", "I live in a hutch", "Tweet Tweet"};
    private String[] answers = {"Dog",
        "Cat",
        "Rabbit",
        "Bird",};
    private String[] name = {};

    public String processInput(String theInput) {
        String theOutput = null;

        //  System.out.println("Welcome to my animal guessing game");

        if (state == WAITING) {
            theOutput = clues[currentAnimal];
            state = SENTCLUE;
        } else if (state == SENTCLUE) {
            if (theInput.equals(answers[currentAnimal])) {
                theOutput = "Correct...Your Score is 1....Want to play again? (y/n)";
                state = ANOTHER;
            } else {
                theOutput = clues2[currentAnimal];
                state = SENTCLUE2;
            }
        } else if (state == SENTCLUE2) {
            if (theInput.equals(answers[currentAnimal])) {
                theOutput = "Correct...Your Score is 2....Want to play again? (y/n)";
                state = ANOTHER;
            } else {
                theOutput = clues3[currentAnimal];
                state = SENTCLUE3;
            }
        } else if (state == SENTCLUE3) {
            if (theInput.equals(answers[currentAnimal])) {
                theOutput = "Correct...Your Score is 3....Want to play again? (y/n)";
                state = ANOTHER;
            } else {
                theOutput = ("it's" + answers[currentAnimal] + " you fool! Want to play again? (y/n)");
                state = ANOTHER;
            }
        } else if (state == ANOTHER) {
            if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                if (currentAnimal == (NUMANIMALS - 1)) {
                    currentAnimal = 0;
                }
                theOutput = clues[currentAnimal];
                // else
                currentAnimal++;

                state = SENTCLUE;
            } else {
                theOutput = "Bye.";
                state = WAITING;
            }
        }
        return theOutput;
    }
}
```

If you need to see the other classes please just ask.

Comment: Why have you tagged "multithreading"? Is the Protocol object used by several threads concurrently? If it is, and because there is no synchronization in your class, random behaviour would not be surprising.

Comment: i tagged multithreading because that is what the unit is called on my university degree. So you say i need to add a synchronization in my class and it will all work okay?

Comment: My question was not about the name of your degree: do you access Protocol instances from several threads or not?

Comment: i only have one thread which contains sockets. but i can have multiple clients all running at the same time. if that still isn't the right answer i don't understand your question? sorry x

Comment: So clients connect via TCP/IP? And for each connected client, you use one KKProtcol-Instance?

Comment: yes. client connects to IP address and port number of 4040, and each client connects to the one KKProtocol

Comment: Most likely the answer is not actually correct... for example, perhaps the theInput string contains a carriage return at the end (or something) and thus isn't actually equal to the string you are comparing against.  I would insert some temporary debug prints that print out the contents of the two strings that you are comparing; most likely it will be obvious then why they aren't matching.  Keep in mind that upper/lower-case difference count also.

Answer (score 0):

Debug the program and set a break point before your first if clause. How do the variables look like? I suppose you've made a trivial error somewhere in your code which will reveal itself while observing what your program actually does.

You could also paste some of your client code here so that someone could understand what is happening. From the comments I understood that nobody quite got how you use the Protocol class.